# SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "impdp"

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Need Help ..

i am Importing a `.DMP` file on my database , when i am writing my impdp query on SQL , it is returning with this error 
I have no idea what this error is

> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "impdp ... " Rest of the line
>   ignored

my command is

```
impdp user/pass directory=DUMPS dumpfile=filedumpname.dmp logfile=name.log full=yes
```

Answer (score 36):

`SP2-0734` is a SQL*Plus error.

`impdp` is a standalone utility, not a SQL*Plus command. You need to run it from the OS command line.

-- This means that impdp is Windows command, not part of sqlplus :-) --

Comment: ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation

Comment: Was the `DUMPS` directory defined in the database (check the `dba_directories` catalog view)? Does your OS user have write privileges on the directory path?

Comment: When i Go on and write the same command on Command line
i get this error

**ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation**

Even ive got the .dmp file and log file with the same name

Comment: @user2322846 - you already said that; the `.dmp` file has to be in the OS directory that is referred to by the `DUMPS` database directory object (in `all_directories` or `dba_directories` as Marco said), and Oracle has to have read/write permission to that OS directory and the file. Please add new info to the question - show the directory definition and OS ownership/permissions...

Comment: This also applies to expdp, the equivalent export command, if anyone else the same error I did.

Answer (score 5):

This error is produced because `impdp` **is not an SQLPlus command.**

### Resolved

If you try to run this as a sqlplus command, you get an error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>sqlplus sys/oracle@orcl as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Nov 7 12:03:56 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> impdp system/oracle@orcl directory=dp schemas=SCDB dumpfile=SCDB.DMP logfile=SCDB.log  

SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "impdp syst..." - rest of line ignored.
```

Indeed, you have to open a new terminal and run the command there:

```
C:\Windows\system32>impdp system/oracle@orcl directory=dp schemas=SCDB dumpfile=SCDB.DMP logfile=SCDB.log

Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Nov 7 12:10:48 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
```

Comment: if want to follow detailed tutorial on export & import than here [Oracle Export Import Utility | Oracle 11g Administration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iy40SPnyyN4)

Answer (score -1):

I have tried all ways but finally I got that **we must change encoding to ANSI** for all (.pck,.tps,.typ,.fnc) files.I hope this will help you ;)